# Is it possible to extend a FAT16b partition and preserve the boot sector?

Tags: windows, partitioning, fat16

I have a bootable USB thumbstick with FreeDOS. It's 512 MB FAT16B. The thumb drive itself is 4 GB, and I'd like to extend the bootable partition as much as possible (FAT16B supports at least 2 GB partitions, possibly 4 GB).

```
DISKPART> detail partition

Partition 1
Type  : 06
Hidden: No
Active: Yes
Offset in Bytes: 32256

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 6     I   FD-SETUP     FAT    Removable    511 MB  Healthy
```

The catch is that `diskpart` refuses to extend this partition:

```
DISKPART> extend

Virtual Disk Service error:
The volume cannot be extended because the file system does not support it.
```

Is it doable? I don't mind losing the files as I can back them up and then restore, but I don't have any simple way of restoring the boot sector so I'd rather not lose it.

Answer (score 0):

[FAT16B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT16B)
is a pretty old format, dating from before Windows NT.
So everything you do is going to be experimental in nature.

I would therefore counsel taking a backup image of the thumb drive in a format
that can be restored. If possible, do the experiments on a virtual copy
rather than on the real drive.
I would suggest the VirtualBox disk formats of VDI or VMDK formats,
for reasons listed below.

Here are some suggestions:

- Download VirtualBox images for older virtual machines exist for download
  in the webpage
  [Virtual Disk Images](http://virtualdiskimages.weebly.com/virtualbox.html).
  You could try an image up to and including Windows NT to resize the partition.
- Linux might still support this format when mounted as type `MSDOS`.
- Some third-party
  [partition editor](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-partition-management-software.htm)
  might know how to handle this format.

(I can only give theoretical advice since I have no personal experience with FAT16B.)